# Система управления вкладами (PHP+MySQL)

Tags: php, cms, книги, структуры, mysql

Заказана система управления вкладами (PHP+MySQL), через интернет, ( как пополнять и выводить, научили нужные API, права пользователей хорошо описаны в ТЗ и в статье на хабре достойная модель), но терзаю себя структурой базы данных, как правильно хранить платежные операции (в одной таблице или в нескольких -входящие и исходящие), как будет удобнее делать выборки для клиента и администратора, неужели это все одна таблица??? 
Может кто знает готовые библиотеки? Если есть на других языках, платные,  или книги напишите, мне нужна любая зацепка.

- P.S1  Если вопрос не сюда, то   направьте на путь истинный.
- P.S2  С   1С - люди не дружат.
- P.S3  И сильно   не пинайте, прошу совета, а не делать   за меня.

Comment: Собственно, суть вопроса не совсем ясна.

Comment: тут стоит вопрос как логичней устроить структуру базы данных, и как ими потом управлять ( пытаюсь набросать  в блокноте - получается ерунда). Не хватает финансовой компоненты, а именно вклады ( пополнение, начисление % и снятие).

Comment: > неужели это все одна таблица?

А что вас пугает? Таблица на текущие балансы клиентов, таблица на операции, процедурки или интерфейс приложения на сверку баланса и реузльтата операций.

> Может кто знает готовые библиотеки?

PDO, Symfony, Phalcon

> пытаюсь набросать в блокноте

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

> Не хватает финансовой компоненты, а именно вклады

Все, что можно сказать по такому вопросу - это что где-то нужно поле decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел на просторах интернета (а точнее на хабре).
Мне даже этого будет много: будет одна валюта.
Учет комисий продумаю отдельно.
Реализация: php+mysql

[image]

Comment: только не забудь везде pk добавить)
и если это вклады, то у них есть скроки, открытие, закрытие, где здесь это хранится?